# bit shifiting, shifting right 4 bits

Tags: c

so I'm doing bit shifting for C

00001010 >> 4
shouldn't give 
0000000?

because I'm shifting the bit to 4 times right, which is same as dividing by 4. 
but on my notes it says 
10101000 
is the notes wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to compile that snippet and see the result for yourself?

Comment: @Zereges how do I compile that, I'm not sure how to write that with code?

Comment: It should give 00000000, 1010 >> 1 = 0101, 1010 >> 2 = 0010, 1010 >> 3 = 0001, 1010 >> 4 = 0000.

Comment: Shifting 4 times to the right is actually equivalent to dividing by 2 to the power of 4, or 16, not dividing by four

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each shift is the same as dividing the value by 2. Shifting to the right four times is like dividing by 2 four times. It's integer math so any fractional portions are truncated.

Assuming `00001010` (10) is binary notation, the results are as follows:

Shift 1: `00000101` (5)
Shift 2: `00000010` (2)
Shift 3: `00000001` (1)
Shift 4: `00000000` (0)

So the result is indeed 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your notes are wrong. `printf("%d\n", strtol("00001010", 0, 2) >> 4)` produces “0”.

Answer (score 0):

**Right shifting** of 00001010 bin (10 dec) 4 times will give you indeed : 00000000 bin (0 dec)
while **left shifting** 4 times of : 00001010 bin (10 dec) will give you : 10100000 bin (160 dec **Edited**)

Comment: doesn't >> this mean shift right? hmm according to your answer my note is wrong and I'm right......

Comment: You'r right. >> means right shifting, you'r also right with your answer. The note is wrong

Comment: 10100000 bin is 160 dec (128+32) not 80

Comment: @Dipstick you'r right, I mistakenly calculated 1010000 and not 10100000.